# Is there a way to programmatically rollback transactions in JooQ?

Tags: transactions, jooq

In our application, we use an `Either` monad to convey failures. As per the  [Jooq transaction management](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.10/manual/sql-execution/transaction-management/) docs, both `@Transactional` and `DslContext.transaction` require an `Exception` to be thrown to trigger the transaction rollback. We'd prefer to commit or rollback the transaction based on the state of the Either.

Psuedo-code of what we need looks like this:

```java
public class DomainService {

    private DSLContext dslContext;

    public Either<SomeError, String> businessOperation() {
        return transactional(configuration ->
                firstDatabaseChange(configuration)
                .flatMap(i -> secondDatabaseChange(configuration)));

    }

    private Either<SomeError, String> firstDatabaseChange(
             DSLContext dslContext) {
        //Mutate the Db in some way
    }

    private Either<SomeError, String> secondDatabaseChange(
             DSLContext dslContext) {
        //Mutate the Db in some way
    }


    /* How do we implement this method */
    private Either<SomeError, String> transactional(Function<DSLContext, 
             Either<SomeError, String>> function) {
        return function.apply(dslContext)
                .onSuccess(i -> /*Commit the transaction */)
                .onFailure(i -> /*Rollback the transaction*/);
    }
}
```

I have the following working implementation of the `transactional` method that feels  like a hack. (Interestingly, the `@Transactional` annotation is required for rollbacks to work even though we don't throw any exceptions). Is there a better way to do this?

```java
@Transactional
public <T> Either<SomeError, T> transactional(Function<DSLContext, 
         Either<SomeError, T>> function) {
    Connection connection = dslContext.parsingConnection();

    try {
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        Either<SomeError, T> either = function.apply(dslContext);
        if (either.isSuccess()) {
            connection.commit();
        } else {
            connection.rollback();
        }
        return result;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        log.error("SqlException encountered", e);
        return SomeError.failure(e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        try {
            connection.rollback();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            log.error("Exception encountered while rolling back", e1);
        }
        return SomeError.failure(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you think your implementation is a hack. You will simply have to do it yourself. You might as well just remove the implementation from your question, and put it there as an answer to your own question.

Comment: @LukasEder Thanks for the quick reply. 

I was hoping that there was another API in Jooq (that I have not noticed) that would allow me to achieve this without dropping down to the `Connection` level.

In addition, I am worried about the implications of using `parsingConnection` directly. 
Do you have an idea on why `@Transactional` is still needed to get this to work?

Comment: There's an alternative, procedural API on the roadmap: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5376. I don't know how `parsingConnection` is related, and why `@Transactional` is involved here. I guess your question is not really complete, with respect to the latter...

Comment: `parsingConnection` is tagged as an experimental feature. Hence, I was wondering if it would have any issues when used for transaction management. From the issue that you linked, I see that I can use `dslContext.connectionResult` to achieve the same result


`@Transactional` should ideally not be present but what we find is that `connection.rollback()` does not seem to actually do anything when the annotation is missing. However, this might be very specific to how our application is setup.

Comment: Oh, you just tried to get a hold of *any* JDBC `Connection` from jOOQ? Yes, `DSLContext.connection()` or `connectionResult()` is the way to go. Don't use `parsingConnection()`. The Javadoc is very clear about its purpose :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by [Lukas Seder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/521799/lukas-eder), a procedural API is on Jooq's roadmap: github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5376

Until this is released, you can achieve the required behaviour as below:

```java
public <T> Either<SomeError, T> transactional(Function<DSLContext,
        Either<SomeError, T>> function) {
    return dslContext.connectionResult(connection -> {
        try {
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            Either<SomeError, T> either = function.apply(dslContext);
            if (either.isSuccess()) {
                connection.commit();
            } else {
                connection.rollback();
            }
            return result;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.error("SqlException encountered", e);
            return SomeError.failure(e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                connection.rollback();
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                log.error("Exception encountered while rolling back", e1);
            }
            return SomeError.failure(e);
        }
    });
}
```